# Prove the following expression is true.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ be arbitrary points in $[a,b]$ and let $$Q(x)= \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} (x-x_i)$$Now suppose $f$ is an n times differentiable function and tha P is a polynomial function of degree $\leq n$ such that $P(x_i)=f(x_i)$ for $i=1,...,n+1$. Show that for each $x \in [a,b]$ there is a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that  $$f(x)-P(x)=Q(x) \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}$$
>     **Hint**:consider the function $$F(t)=Q(x)(f(t)-P(t))-Q(t)(f(x)-P(x))$$ show that $F$ is zero at n+2 different points in $[a,b]$ and use the fact that "If $f$ is an $n$ times differentiable function and that $f(x)=0$ for $n+1$ different values of $x$ then there exists $x$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)$=0

**My Attempt**

The function $F$ considered here is a function of $t$ alone and the value of $x$ is regarde as a constant. Of course of we change the value of $x$ then we get a different function $F$. In any case if $x$ is not one of the $x_i$ $i=1,...,n+1$ then $F$ vanishes at $n+2$ points;
$\bullet$ the $n+1$ points $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$
$\bullet$ the point $x$.

Hence there is a point $c \in [a,b]$ where $F^{n+1}(c)=0$.

Now to calculate $F^(n+1)$ remembering that $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ and that $Q$ is degree exactly $n+1$.

Differentiating $$F(t)=Q(x)(f(t)-P(t))-Q(t)(f(x)-P(x))$$ $n+1$ times we get $$F^{(n+1)}(t)=f^{(n+1)}Q(x)-(n+1)!f(x)+(n+1)!P(x)$$ at point $c \in [a,b]$ we have $$0=F^{(n+1)}(c)=f^{(n+1)}(c)Q(x)-(n+1)!f(x)+(n+1)!P(x)$$ rearranging we get $$f(x)-P(x)=Q(x) \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}$$

Is this correct?? 
Any advice would be much appreciated,
Reference: Spivac Calculus

Comment: For completeness, you could add to your proof the case when $x$ is one of the $x_i$. Of course, then your equation hols for arbitrary $c$. Apart from that, this looks fine to me.